# How to show, contenttype, modified date and modified by in a content query webpart with a custom xsl?

Tags: 2010, 2013

I checked the default Item.xsl provisioned by sharepoint, and I created a new xsl file based on this one.

The one that I want to start from is the one with the docIcon, it render the icon of the file type(word,pdf, etc), the document name, but now I wont to render also, Modifed date, modified by, and content type.

As I dont have experience with XSL, thats why I ask here for some help.

```
   <xsl:template name="MyStyle" match="Row[@Style='MyStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Type</h3></td>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>File Name</h3></td>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Content Type</h3></td>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Modified</h3></td>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Modified By</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(@DocumentIconImageUrl) != 0">
               <div class="image-area-left">
                   <img class="image" src="{@DocumentIconImageUrl}" title="" />
               </div>
           </xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="link-item">
               <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
               <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
                   <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
                     <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                       <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
                     </xsl:attribute>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
                     <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                       <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
                     </xsl:attribute>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
               </a>
               <div class="description">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
               </div>
           </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ContentType" 
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@DateModified" 
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Editor" 
        </td>        
    </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You posted the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187599/how-to-show-contenttype-modified-date-and-modified-by-in-a-content-query-webpa -- please don't post the same question in multiple places. Read http://www.excelguru.ca/node/7

Comment: Better still, read this question on the community FAQ for StackOverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Comment: I ask it in both places because I like it, they are both sharepoint related, and they are both programming related. I like it do do it that way to get more attention and views, and possible answers.  If this is not allowed, then you HAVE to remove the sharpeoint TAG from stackexchange.com because otherwise this site doesnt make any sense if the tag exists there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your own XSL template, in order to add more columns values to your template add additional `<xsl:value-of select="" />` elements in your template.

Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Modified" /> <!-- Shows last modified -->
<xsl:value-of select="@Author" /> <!-- Shows created by -->
```

`@` tells the XSL to show the value of the specified column within the current row if the column exists or is not overriden through the CQWP.

Hope it helps :)